# Non-localized version of MinGW/MSYS2?

Tags: localization, mingw, msys2, non-english

Is there a way to download MinGW/MSYS2 with gcc, that is not localized?
Localized gcc causes all warnings to become errors in CodeBlocks, if the system language is not English.
This bug is also reported here:

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,9489.msg67120.html

The thread also contains a working solution to the problem, but if one could download a non-localized version in the first place, this would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gcc & G++ in mingw use the environment variable LC_ALL to define the language at top level (if this variable is set), defaulting with the system locale if available, and then english if the locale does not exist.

If you want to force those tools to output their messages in english, just add/edit the environment variable **LC_ALL** with the value **en_US.UTF-8**

Comment: That's not a valid locale on Windows. Just `set LANG=C` and be done with it :)

Comment: @rubenvb It is not a windows locale, it is a Mingw locale, we're not trying to make windows do something there.

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty sure the following is not the "recommended solution", but I personally gave up on trying to find one. So: My locale is `da` (Danish) which causes exactly the kind of problem you describe.

My solution?
Simply erase the locale used, causing the system to default to english: i.e. in my case erase the folder:

```
C:\MinGW\share\locale\da
```

(In more recent versions the location might be for example `msys64\usr\share\locale\sv` where in this case `sv` represents Swedish.)

Why on earth anyone coding in `C/C++` would want their tools to output localized error-messages is beyond me...

Comment: Well, i guess it's the easiest solution to this problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Although this is (currently) my preferred solution, I just discovered that whenever I install a new package, the language (in my case `sv`) is installed back again. So I might have to delete that folder every time I install a new package ... (SIGH!)

Answer (score 3):

Use the commmand

```
locale -a
```

to see a list of enabled locales.
To use USA English, I set below environment variables in my bash's source file

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

After installing [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/#installation),
I tried :

```
$ drivel
-bash: drivel: kommandot finns inte
```

As you can see, `kommandot finns inte` is *not* English.
So I ran :
<sup>1</sup>

```
$ echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/profile.d/english.sh
```

Then I closed and restarted MSYS2, and tried running `drivel` again :

```
$ drivel
-bash: drivel: command not found
```

Yay! – It's now in English: `command not found`.

---

<sup>1</sup>
My solution is inspired by
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105143).