# Garbled compiler (MinGW) output

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, mingw

I've been trying to compile some basic linked-list example i took somewhere else.

The problem i am having is more of user kind. I guess the picture says it all:

[image]

What's the reason for all the weird symbols ? Normal MinGW output should look something like error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘element*’

That's the problem i am having, but i would be happy to receive explanation on the error itself. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct element {
       int info;
       struct element *next;
};
int main(void){
struct element *head, *node;
int arv;
head = NULL;
printf("Enter number! (0 to exit)");
scanf("%d",&arv);
while (arv != 0){
      node = malloc(sizeof *node);
      node->next = head;
      node->info = arv;
      head = node;
      printf("Enter number! (0 to exit)");
      scanf("%d",&arv);
}
}
```

***Edit***
Solved ! Thanks for the info guys. Similar question:

[mingw g++ gives warnings in wrong language (german instead of english)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191063/mingw-g-gives-warnings-in-wrong-language-german-instead-of-english)

[Non-localized version of MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268379/non-localized-version-of-mingw)

As for the solution, i removed everything from "\mingw\share\locale". Might not be the best practice though.

Comment: malloc returns a void*... you need to cast it. As for the compiler output I have no idea. Are you using the correct compiler version for your architecture?

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't call that "messy", I'd say that is "garbled". I was ready to post a sympathetic answer informing you that, indeed, the output from a C++ compiler is often "messy". :-)

Comment: Can you post the output of the `set` command, if issued inside that console window.

Comment: change to `node = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));`

Comment: If the answer was correct and helpful for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am wildly guessing here, but your compiler *might* be outputting error messages localized in your language using UTF-8, and your terminal does not understand UTF-8 and displays it in some Windows codepage. Are your language settings configured for a non-latin language?

Comment: +1: with the information provided that is what I would guess as well (see my comment/hint on the question). Only thing strange is, that part of the message "In function '%s':" doesn't seem to be localized.