# Custom hashmap giving compilation error using gcc on linux

Tags: c++

below implementation of UtlHashMap got compiled in Visual Studio 2008 but on GCC 4.4 giving below errors

---

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

static size_t DEFAULT_DIC_SIZE = 1023;



template <class K, class V>
class hash_map
{
public:

    // for the iterator 
    // ??typedef V allocator_type;
    typedef V value_type; 
    typedef V& reference;
    typedef V* pointer;
    typedef const V& const_reference;
    typedef const V* const_pointer;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;

    typedef std::pair<K,V* > KeyValuePair;
    typedef std::pair<short,std::list<KeyValuePair > > AccessPair;


    hash_map(unsigned (*hashFunc)(const K&), size_t size = DEFAULT_DIC_SIZE);
    hash_map(const hash_map& right); // NOTE THIS WILL SHALLOW COPY DATA
    ~hash_map() {clearAndDestroy();}
    //bool insert(const K* key, pointer value);
    void insertKeyAndValue(K* key, pointer value);
    //const K* findKey (const K* key) const;
    pointer findValue(const K* key) const;
    const K* findKeyAndValue(const K* key, V*& value);
    bool isEmpty() const {return (items_ == 0);}
    void clearAndDestroy();
    unsigned long long buckets() const { return bucketsUsed_; }
    unsigned long long items() const { return items_; }
    K* remove (const K* key);

    int cins;
    clock_t tins;
    int cnb;
    clock_t tnb;

    class iterator
    {
    public:
        typedef V value_type; 
        typedef V& reference;
        typedef V* pointer;
        typedef const V& const_reference;
        typedef const V* const_pointer;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef size_t size_type;
        //typedef forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

        typedef typename std::vector<AccessPair >::iterator vecIter;
        typedef typename std::list<KeyValuePair >::iterator pairLIter; 

        iterator() {}
        // construction also allowed with vector::iterator for implicit constructions
        iterator(vecIter& vit, bool bend = false);
        // copy constructor
        iterator(const iterator& rhs):  curBucket_(rhs.curBucket_), curData_(rhs.curData_), theend_(rhs.theend_) {} 
        virtual ~iterator() {}
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& it); 
        iterator& operator=(const vecIter& vit);
        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const ;
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const ;
        iterator& operator++(); 
        iterator operator++(int); 
        reference operator*() { return *(curData_->second); }
        pointer operator->()  { return &(operator*()); }
        K* key() const { return &(curData_->first); }
        pointer value() const { return (curData_->second);}


    protected:
        vecIter curBucket_;
        pairLIter curData_;

    private:
        bool theend_;

        bool bucketEmpty (); 
        bool lastBucket ();
        void moveOn();

    };

    class const_iterator : public iterator
    {
    public:

        const_iterator () {}
        const_iterator (const const_iterator& ci):iterator(ci) {}
        const_iterator (const iterator& i):iterator(i) {}
        const_iterator(const vecIter& vit, bool bend = false):iterator(const_cast<vecIter&>( vit),bend) {}

        ~const_iterator() {}

        // these dynamic_cast to references are safe (aren't they? Must be we're making the call!)
        const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator& ci) {return dynamic_cast<const_iterator&>(iterator::operator=(ci));}
        bool operator==(const const_iterator& ci) const {return iterator::operator==(ci);}
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator& ci) const {return iterator::operator!=(ci);}

        const_iterator& operator++() {return const_iterator(iterator::operator++());}
        const_iterator operator++(int i) {return const_iterator(iterator::operator++(i)); }

        const_reference operator*() const {return *(curData_->second);}
        const_pointer operator->() const {return &(operator*());}
        const K* key() const { return iterator::key(); }
        const_pointer value() const { return iterator::value();}

    };

    const_iterator begin() const;  
    const_iterator end() const; 
    iterator begin() ;
    iterator end(); 


private:
    hash_map();
    //void operator=();

    mutable std::vector<AccessPair > buckets_;
    size_t size_;
    unsigned long long bucketsUsed_;
    unsigned long long items_;

    unsigned (*mHashFunc)(const K&);

};


template <class K, class V>
hash_map<K,V>::hash_map(unsigned (*hashFunc)(const K&), size_t size)
: size_ (size)
, mHashFunc (hashFunc)
, bucketsUsed_ (0)
, items_ (0)
{
    if(size <= 0) size = 1;// protection against some rogue initialisation.
    cins = tins = cnb = tnb = 0;
    buckets_.resize(size);
    buckets_[size-1].first = 2; //lets hope they are all set to 0
}

template <class K, class V>
hash_map<K,V>::hash_map(const hash_map& right)
{
    buckets_ = right.buckets_;
    items_ = right.items_;
    bucketsUsed_ = right.bucketsUsed_;
    size_ = right.size_;
}

template <class K, class V>
void hash_map<K,V>::insertKeyAndValue(K *key, V *value)
{
    // get the hash value from key
    long hashvalue = mHashFunc(*key);

    // what bucket is it in
    long bucketIdx = hashvalue%size_;

    if (buckets_[bucketIdx].second.empty() )
    {
        ++bucketsUsed_;
        buckets_[bucketIdx].first += 1;
    }
    // do we want to prevent duplicate key being inserted???? 
    // This will allow duplicate keys
    buckets_[bucketIdx].second.push_back(std::pair<K,V*>(*key,value));
    ++items_;
}


template <class K, class V>
V* hash_map<K,V>::findValue(const K* key) const
{
    // get the hash value from key
    long hashvalue = mHashFunc(*key);

    // what bucket is it in
    long bucketIdx = hashvalue%size_;

    if (!buckets_[bucketIdx].second.empty())
    {
        for (std::list<std::pair<K,V*> >::const_iterator it = buckets_[bucketIdx].second.begin(); 
                        it != buckets_[bucketIdx].second.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (it->first == *key)
            {
                return it->second;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


template <class K, class V>
const K* hash_map<K,V>::findKeyAndValue(const K* key, V*& value)
{
    // get the hash value from key and what bucket is it in
    long bucketIdx = mHashFunc(*key)%size_;

    if (!buckets_[bucketIdx].second.empty())
    {
        for (std::list<std::pair<K,V*> >::const_iterator it = buckets_[bucketIdx].second.begin(); 
                        it != buckets_[bucketIdx].second.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (it->first == *key)
            {
                value = it->second;
                return &(it->first);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

template <class K, class V>
K* hash_map<K,V>::remove (const K* key)
{
    // get the hash value from key and what bucket is it in
    long bucketIdx = mHashFunc(*key)%size_;
    if (!buckets_[bucketIdx].second.empty())
    {
        for (std::list<std::pair<K,V*> >::iterator it = buckets_[bucketIdx].second.begin(); 
                        it != buckets_[bucketIdx].second.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (it->first == *key)
            {
                it = buckets_[bucketIdx].second.erase(it); // not sure if I need to delete it->second
                --items_;
                break; // arrhhhh!!!! need to add to a list to delete
            } 
        }

        if ((buckets_[bucketIdx]).second.empty())
        {
            --bucketsUsed_;
            buckets_[bucketIdx].first -= 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

template <class K, class V>
void hash_map<K,V>::clearAndDestroy()
{
    for (std::vector<AccessPair >::iterator it = buckets_.begin(); it != buckets_.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->second.empty() == false)
        {
            it->first -= 1;
            it->second.clear(); // this destroys the contents
        }
    }
    bucketsUsed_ = 0;
    items_ = 0;

}

template <class K, class V>
typename hash_map<K,V>::const_iterator hash_map<K,V>::begin() const  
{
    hash_map<K,V>* ptr = const_cast<hash_map<K,V>*>(this);
    hash_map<K,V>::iterator it = ptr->begin();
    return const_iterator(it);
}

template <class K, class V>
inline typename hash_map<K,V>::const_iterator hash_map<K,V>::end() const  
{
    return const_iterator(buckets_.end(), true);
}

template <class K, class V>
typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator hash_map<K,V>::begin() 
{
    if (bucketsUsed_ == 0) return end();

    for (std::vector<AccessPair >::iterator it = buckets_.begin(); it != buckets_.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->second.empty() == false) return iterator(it);
    }
    // should get here!
    return end();
}

template <class K, class V>
inline typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator hash_map<K,V>::end() 
{
    std::vector<AccessPair >::iterator it = buckets_.end();
    return iterator(it, true); 
}



// --- definition for iterator methods -----

template <class K, class V>
inline hash_map<K,V>::iterator::iterator(vecIter& vit, bool bend)
    : curBucket_ (vit)
    , theend_(bend)
{ 
    if (!bend) curData_ =  curBucket_->second.begin();
}

template <class K, class V>
inline typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator& hash_map<K,V>::iterator::operator=(const typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator& it) 
{
    // this will break if there is nothing inserted at this position
    curBucket_ = it.curBucket_;
    curData_ = it.curData_;
    theend_ = it.theend_;
    return *this; 
}

template <class K, class V>
inline typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator& hash_map<K,V>::iterator::operator=(const vecIter& vit)
{ 
    curBucket_= vit; 
    curData_ = curBucket_->second.begin();
    return *this 
}

template <class K, class V>
bool hash_map<K,V>::iterator::operator==(const typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator& rhs) const 
{ 
    bool b = false; //(curBucket_== rhs.curBucket_ && !theend_ && curData_ == rhs.curData_);
    if (curBucket_== rhs.curBucket_)
    {
        if (!theend_)
        {
            if (curData_ == rhs.curData_)  b = true;
        }
        else
        {
            b = true;
        }
    }
    return b; 
}

template <class K, class V>
inline bool hash_map<K,V>::iterator::operator!=(const typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator& rhs) const 
{ 
    return !(*this==rhs);
}

template <class K, class V>
typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator& hash_map<K,V>::iterator::operator++()
{
    // We don't know if we have been called by user or self recursively
    // however we do know we cant be here is we had moved to the end of the map (beyong the last bucket)
    if (!bucketEmpty()) 
    { 
        // only inc data when we know bucket is not empty
        ++curData_; 
        if (curData_ == curBucket_->second.end())
        {
            // current bucket is not empty, but next data Item is null
            moveOn();
        }
    }              
    else
    {
        // we can only be here if we called our selfs or were assigned to some random position in map (which may not be posible but....)
        // 1. are we at the end now
        moveOn();
    }

    return *this; 
}

template <class K, class V>
inline typename hash_map<K,V>::iterator hash_map<K,V>::iterator::operator++(int)
{ 
    iterator tmp(*this); 
    ++(*this); 
    return tmp; 
} 

template <class K, class V>
inline bool hash_map<K,V>::iterator::bucketEmpty () 
{
    if ((curBucket_->first & 1) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

template <class K, class V>
inline bool hash_map<K,V>::iterator::lastBucket ()
{
    if ((curBucket_->first & 2) > 1) return true;
    return false;
}

template <class K, class V>
inline void hash_map<K,V>::iterator::moveOn()
{
    if (lastBucket())       
    {
        // this is the last bucket, we need to mark it, so when we move on to next bucket (END), 
        // we do not attempt access any data items
        theend_ = true;
    }

    ++curBucket_;
    if (!theend_)
    {
        // OK this is not the last bucket, but at the same time we do not want to return an empty bucket with no data
        if (bucketEmpty())
        {
            ++(*this);
        }
        else
        {
            // we have data we can return - hoora!
            curData_ = curBucket_->second.begin();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âvecIterâ with no type
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: expected â,â or â...â before â&â token
UtlHashMap.h: In constructor âjda::hash_map<K, V>::const_iterator::const_iterator(int)â:
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: expected type-specifier before âvecIterâ
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: expected â>â before âvecIterâ
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: expected â(â before âvecIterâ
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: âvitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: âbendâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h:102: error: expected â{â at end of input
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âconst V& jda::hash_map<K, V>::const_iterator::operator*() constâ:
UtlHashMap.h:114: error: âcurData_â was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âV* jda::hash_map<K, V>::findValue(const K*) constâ:
UtlHashMap.h:195: error: expected â;â before âitâ
UtlHashMap.h:196: error: âitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âconst K* jda::hash_map<K, V>::findKeyAndValue(const K*, V*&)â:
UtlHashMap.h:217: error: expected â;â before âitâ
UtlHashMap.h:218: error: âitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âK* jda::hash_map<K, V>::remove(const K*)â:
UtlHashMap.h:238: error: expected â;â before âitâ
UtlHashMap.h:239: error: âitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âvoid jda::hash_map<K, V>::clearAndDestroy()â:
UtlHashMap.h:263: error: expected â;â before âitâ
UtlHashMap.h:263: error: âitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âjda::hash_map<K, V>::iterator jda::hash_map<K, V>::begin()â:
UtlHashMap.h:295: error: expected â;â before âitâ
UtlHashMap.h:295: error: âitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âjda::hash_map<K, V>::iterator jda::hash_map<K, V>::end()â:
UtlHashMap.h:306: error: expected â;â before âitâ
UtlHashMap.h:307: error: âitâ was not declared in this scope
UtlHashMap.h: In member function âjda::hash_map<K, V>::iterator& jda::hash_map<K, V>::iterator::operator=(const typename std::vector<std::pair<short int, std::list<std::pair<K, V*>, std::allocator<std::pair<K, V*> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<short int, std::list<std::pair<K, V*>, std::allocator<std::pair<K, V*> > > > > >::iterator&)â:
UtlHashMap.h:338: error: expected â;â before â}â token
```

---

Comment: First thing’s first, configure your console’s encoding properly so that you don’t get weird characters (“â”) but the right ones.

Comment: please tell me how to do that even I am getting annoyed by that silly charachter.

Comment: replace vecIter with iterator::vecIter in your const_iterator

Comment: @anonymous Hard to say, I’d have to guess that you’re using MinGW on Windows. Maybe these questions can help you: [mingw g++ gives warnings in wrong language (german instead of english)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10191063) and [Non-localized version of MinGW?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9268379)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you check template usage against new template rules in ISO C++ 2003 standard.

Thanks