# MSYS2 keeps resetting settings

Tags: msys2, non-english

I just have a basic question. MSYS2 keeps resetting my settings when I restart it.
For example, when I change the language from German to English (export LANG=...), it will reset the language after restarting. Only by changing the Windows language can I change the language in MSYS2.

After installing a new program, apparently, this program folder is the new home folder now (?). When I try to change the home directory, it gets reset again after restarting.

EDIT: Alright, so this new software I installed changed my HOME environment variable. I fixed this now.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue this way:

1. Go to *msys/etc/profile.d* directory
2. Create file
   "myenvvars.sh", for example
3. Add all the "export" directives you
   need

So every "export" will be executed every time you run msys.